# Scroll using mousewheel doesn't work on css pseudo selector. Why?

Tags: css, scroll, css-selectors, mousewheel

Here is the css code:

```
div{
  background:silver;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  display:block;
}
div:before{
  content:"adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda adsasd asd ad ad asd asd ad asd asda sad asd a THE END";
  display:block;
  background:blue;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xa0rmdpn/

Try to scroll using mousewheel.

I'm using last version of Opera.

Comment: Very interesting. I can reproduce the issue in Chrome, but not in Firefox.